# How to ask the user to input numbers only in integer?

Tags: c#, if-statement, integer

I want to ask the user to input a number including an if statement option were if he puts letters the last question will be asked again
I've tried this but seemingly it work only for strings

```
        Console.Write("Write a number:");
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (!int.TryParse(age, out num))
            while(!int.TryParse(age, out num))
            {
             Console.WriteLine(...);
             // ....
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's *extract method* for this: we are going to ask user to input valid value until he or she provides it. So we have a *loop*:

```
   private static int ReadInteger(string question) {
     // Keep asking...
     while (true) {
       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(question))
         Console.WriteLine(question);

       // ... until valid value provided
       if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
         return result;

       Console.WriteLine($"Sorry, not a valid integer value; please, try again."); 
     }
   }
```

Then you can use it as

```
   int age = ReadInteger("Please, input age");
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Comment: If an answer was helpful remember to mark it as accepted so others don't try and answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that I'm using in my current project that might help you out, it just checks if the input string only contains numbers:

```
bool isDigitsOnly(string inputString)
{
    foreach (char c in inputString)
    {
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You might have to modify it a little bit to fit your needs, but it should work well enough

Comment: Thanks for your feedback that worked for me as well

Comment: This will however also accept the input "12345678901234567890" which is too long to be converted to `int`. And it won't accept "-1" which is a perfectly valid `int`.